# DateTime converts wrong when variable has 1900's as year in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to convert the object to `datetime` datatype. Type conversion is happening but output is wrong.
Also I want to do type conversion for series also. Same behavior is observed.

```
 d1="22/2/56"
 d2=datetime.datetime.strptime(d1,'%d/%m/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 print(d2)
```

Actual output: `2056-02-22`

Expected output: `1956-02-22`